# abductive reasoning in many fields of study

Tags: logic, epistemology, deduction, reason, abduction

In continuation of the discussion [What is the relation between abductive reasoning and fallacy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92822/what-is-the-relation-between-abductive-reasoning-and-fallacy) my question is that if medical science judiciary history all uses abductive reasoning (almost all the fields ) where is the scope of using deductive reasoning or how can we incorporate deductive with abductive for better clarity and understanding ?